# How to disable or ignore a test in bash automated testing system?

Tags: bats-core

I am having a set of .bat files . each file contains some tests. How can i disable one of the test ?

the following is an example

```
bashTester.sh

#! /bin/bash

bats -T --gather-test-outputs-in $OUTPUT/createEnvironment.bat
bats -T --gather-test-outputs-in $OUTPUT/protocolTest.bat
```

I want to ignore a test in the protocolTest.bat . The following are my tests in the `protocolTest.bats` file.

```
protocolTest.bats

@test "test1-protocol" {

}

@test "test2-protocol" {

}
```

how can i ignore or disable the test "test2-protocol" ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to skip tests with BATS:

- Marking a test as skipped in the code
- Filtering test when running `bats`

Which solutions works best for you will depend on the context of your question.

### `skip` in the code

Quoting [the "`skip`: Easily skip tests" section](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/writing-tests.html#skip-easily-skip-tests) of the manual:

> Tests can be skipped by using the `skip` command at the point in a test you wish to skip.
> ...
> Optionally, you may include a reason for skipping:
> ...
> Or you can skip conditionally

To give you an example of all 3 of these:

```
@test "test2-protocol" {
    skip # Just skip the test

    skip "Some reason to skip this test" # Skip with a reason

    if [ foo != bar ]; then
        skip "foo isn't bar" # Skip under specific circumstances
    fi
}
```

This last option, using a condition, would also allow you to skip the test when a certain environmental variable is (or isn't) set, giving you more fine-grained control.

For instance, if the test code look like this:

```
@test "test2-protocol" {
    if [ "${SKIP_TEST}" = 'test2-protocol' ]; then
        skip "Skipping test2-protocol"
    fi
}
```

and `bats` is called like this:

```sh
SKIP_TEST='test2-protocol' bats -T --gather-test-outputs-in $OUTPUT/protocolTest.bat
```

the test will be skipped. Calling `bats` without setting `SKIP_TEST` will run all test, without skipping anything.

### `--filter` on run

Quoting the [the "Usage" section of the manual](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html):

```
  -f, --filter <regex>      Only run tests that match the regular expression
```

As the filter needs a match, we need to [negate](https://www.wordnik.com/words/negate) the test you want to exclude.

Given the example, something like this should work:

```sh
bats -T --gather-test-outputs-in $OUTPUT/protocolTest.bat --filter 'test[^2]-protocol'
```

More information about negating regexes can be [found on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=negate+regex+is%3Aquestion)